# How can I add unicode glyphs using just the keyboard?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I want to use glyphs in my text with keyboard shortcuts.

Say an endmark, instead of placing it through the glyphs panel I want to use my keyboard.

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: This question belongs on the SuperUser stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're in InDesign and you are editing text in a container:

### Windows

1. Press and hold down the Alt key
2. Press the + (plus) key on the numeric keypad
3. Type the hexidecimal unicode value
4. Release the Alt key

### Mac

You need to do a little setup first (example using Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.2)

1. System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources
2. Click the **+** button at the bottom of the left-hand pane
3. A sheet will slide down. Type **Unicode** in the Search field
4. Click **Unicode Hex Input** in the right-hand pane
5. Click **Add** *Now you have Unicode Input enabled for the system*
6. I always turn "Show input menu in menu bar" **ON** so I can see the
   input mode I have selected
7. Still in Keyboard, click the Shortcuts tab
8. Select **Input Sources** on the left
9. Select **BOTH** "Select the previous input source" and "Select next
   source in Input menu"
10. Set the shortcuts to something useful.

Now you can select your regular keyboard layout or Unicode Hex Input from the keyboard.

When you're in **Unicode Hex Input**:

Simply hold down Option key and type the hex code of the character you want (no need to type the + (plus) sign).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, you can also install [WinCompose](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose) which gives you a compose key. Then you can use sequences such as <kbd>Compose</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> to obtain ® and the likes. WinCompose also has a searchable list of all symbols it supports and allows you to add your own sequences as well.